# Declare navigation properties as virtual IReadOnlyCollection<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many, ef-fluent-api

I have one-to-many relationship between App and Versions

```
public class App
{       
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AppId { get; set; }        

    public string Name { get; set; }       

    public virtual ICollection<Versions> AppVersions { get; set; } =
        new List<Versions>();

}

public class Versions

{    
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int VersionId { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; } 

[ForeignKey("AppId")]
public virtual App MyApp { get; set; }
}
```

//fluent api to avoid the cascade delete

```
modelBuilder.Entity<App>()
        .HasMany(c => c.AppVersions)
        .WithRequired(c => c.MyApp)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.AppId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false)
```

This works fine but if i change the `ICollection` to `IReadOnlyCollection` (as i do not want support adding and removing of this field from the application I get the following error on 'HasMany' of fluent api.

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0411  The type arguments for method EntityTypeConfiguration.HasMany(Expression>>) 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.**

So I am not sure is this the correct way or not.

Comment: In pre EF Core the *minimal* requirement for collection navigation property is `ICollection<T>`. Hence want or not, you can't use `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: @IvanStoev and same goes for 'IEnumerable<T>' ?

Comment: Indeed, since it's not `ICollection<T>` derived.